# Is [curvesmoothing] a duplicate of [smoothing]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[curvesmoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curvesmoothing) seems to be a direct duplicate of [smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smoothing).
It only has 9 questions and they could all be tagged 'smoothing'.
Should we merge?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curvesmoothing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smoothing

Comment: Merging is used when editing the questions to change the tag is impossible to do; for example, if the questions using [tag:curvesmoothing] are 2000, the tag is really a synonym of the other one, and for each question from which the tag is removed there is a new question using it, then merging would be the correct step. With 9 questions, merging is barely necessary, if really there are two tags being used for the same purpose.

Comment: Since I'm new to MSO I don't know that. In either circumstance I usefully pointed out that the tags are duplicates, so I should be being thanked not downvoted. If people wanted to be constructive not antagonistic, they would simply suggest change to the title.